# GROUP BY with condition giving me some part of real results

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have three tables to maintain betting system in MySQL. Our users say, somehow some of betslips didn't change "won status" even though they are won. So I'm looking for these wrong results. Shortly, I need IDs from betslips table which having matched choices (all should be a match) from betslips_inner table with bet results from bets table.

```
SELECT a.ID,a.betslip,a.bet,a.choice,c.result
FROM betslips_inner a JOIN
     betslips b JOIN
     bets c
     ON b.won=0 AND a.betslip=b.ID AND c.ID=a.bet AND a.choice=c.result
GROUP BY a.betslip
having count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM betslips_inner WHERE betslip = a.betslip)
```

This query gets me some results. However, it seems it's only giving me a little part of real results I need.

What am I missing here? Why this query leads me to true results but not all true results?

EXAMPLE DATA

```
BET
-------
ID result
1  1
2  2
3  1
4  1
-------

BETSLIPS
-------
ID won
1  0
2  0
-------

BETSLIPS_INNER
-------
ID betslip bet choice
1  1       1    1
2  1       2    2
3  1       3    1
4  2       4    2
5  2       3    1
-------
```

So expected betslip should be the betslip with ID:1. Second betslip has a winning match inside but not an "all-match".

For example, below query;

```
SELECT a.bet as bet, a.choice as choice, b.result as result, c.ID as ID, 
c.won as won
FROM betslips_inner a 
JOIN bet b JOIN betslips c ON 
b.ID=a.bet AND c.ID=a.betslip 
WHERE a.betslip = 5128919
```

gives me this,

```
bet   choice result ID      won
66897 2      2      5128919 0
66895 1      1      5128919 0
66695 2      2      5128919 0
38196 2      2      5128919 0
66995 2      2      5128919 0
66686 1      1      5128919 0
66715 1      1      5128919 0
```

But I cannot find betslip with ID 5128919 with first query. (I should be since it's an all-match betslip with won=0)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What happens when you move the `b.won=0` out of the JOIN clause and inside the WHERE clause ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my question.

Comment: @IVOGELOV it's giving me same results.

Comment: Your query applied on your sample data gives the desired answer - ID:1

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes, it's giving true results but not giving all true results. http://666kb.com/i/dvforvghvoydyf39x.png

Comment: We do not have an example for values which should produce a result but actually miss from the query

Comment: I re-edited with helpful data on the case @IVOGELOV

Comment: I am getting better in guessing with each day I spend on SO .... So my guess is `SELECT betslips.id FROM betslips LEFT JOIN betslips_inner ON betslips.id = betslip LEFT JOIN bets ON bet.id = betslips_inner.bet WHERE won = 0 AND choice <> result GROUP BY betslips.id`

Comment: Unfortunately even if I tried to change and run it it doesn't work @IVOGELOV

Comment: Okay, if it does not work then try like this `SELECT id FROM betslips WHERE won = 0 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM betslips_inner LEFT JOIN bets ON bets.id = betslips_inner.bet WHERE betslip = betslips.id AND choice <> result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that you're looking for something like the SQL below.

Which uses a LEFT JOIN on BETS.

And the HAVING limits to the same results between the BETSLIPS_INNER and the BETS table.

```
SELECT slipin.betslip, 
COUNT(slipin.ID) as total_inner, 
COUNT(bet.ID) as total_bet_matching
FROM BETSLIPS_INNER slipin
JOIN BETSLIPS slip ON (slip.ID = slipin.betslip)
LEFT JOIN BETS bet ON (bet.ID = slipin.bet AND bet.result = slipin.choice)
WHERE slip.won = 0
GROUP BY slipin.betslip
HAVING COUNT(slipin.ID) = COUNT(bet.ID);
```

Based on the sample data it'll return betslip 1.
But not betslip 2.

**Here's the sample data:**

```
create table BETS (ID int, result int);
create table BETSLIPS (ID int, won int);
create table BETSLIPS_INNER (ID int, betslip int, bet int, choice int);
insert into BETS (ID, result)  values (1,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,2);
insert into BETSLIPS (ID, won) values (1,0),(2,0);
insert into BETSLIPS_INNER (ID, betslip, bet, choice) values
(1,1,1,1),(2,1,2,2),(3,1,3,1),
(4,2,4,2),(5,2,3,1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this one, but having difficulties to understand what's slipin table.

Comment: It's just an alias name for BETSLIPS_INNER. ;)

Comment: You just ended my desperate nightmare. Thank you kind stranger! So much learned about SQL from this thread also.

Comment: Well, good that it helped. :) But you probably noticed some differences. One thing is that it's best to put the ON clause with the JOIN's they belong. Makes the SQL more readable. Because the JOIN syntax was intended to seperate the link criteria from the search criteria.